# Sizes of buttons with images

Tags: image, button, size, codenameone

In my app I have two instances of the same kind of button (an own class I've made which subclasses Button and sets a specific UIID and also does some other things...)

One of them is added into a BoxLayout Y which is added as center in a BorderLayout.  The other component in the BoxLayout is a label which is above the button.

The other one is added in a GridLayout which is added as south in another BorderLayout.  The grid is 1 row and 3 columns (the button is one of the columns).  The horizontal size is ample so there is no need to make it smaller to fit horizontally.

My issue is that these two buttons are of different sizes.  The first one is significantly larger than the second.  I suspect that the second one has been made smaller somewhere in the process but I can't understand why.  I would like to have the first button be the same size as the other one, or the same vertical size (with the corresponding horizontal size) as the label above it.

I have tried to use the setHeight and setPreferredHeight of the button.  The result was that the button was actually made smaller, but not the image on it so the image was cropped.

I have also tried to use the setSameHeight with the first button and the label above it, but the result was only that the label was made larger.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is the GridLayout Container.

What GridLayout does is that it divides the Container into 3 equal sizes and shrink anything in any of the column to fit within its space.

TableLayout on the hand is similar to GridLayout except that it's flexible. It adjusts itself to accommodate the size of the biggest component in it.

Change that GridLayout to TableLayout with the same number of rows and columns, and the Buttons would be fixed.

I will suggest you also add the second button to a BoxLayout container before placing it in the TableLayout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...  But I actually want to do the reverse...  I want to shrink the first button, not make the second larger.  So, how can I control the size of the first to make it smaller?

Comment: In that case, place the first button inside a GridLayout. with 3 columns. If you share a sketch or design of what you're trying to achieve, there might be a better way